# I i'm not able to deploy my android application on my device developed using xamarin on visual studio 2019

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I have built my xamarin android application using visual studio 2019 latest version. I have set the target framework as android 10 (Q) level 29 and minimum as level 21. I have generated the apk and signed it. When i install on my device ( sumsumg J8 with android version 10) the app installs ok. The first page opens which is a login page. When i click login button it crashes immediately. I have tried this even with a blank app with only one button doing nothing but the application crashes immediately

Comment: what do the device logs show?  If you deploy from VS does the debugger show an exception?  Have you tried a crash reporting tool like appcenter.ms or raygun.io?

Comment: Okay, i had not tried to debug on relase mode. How can i debug on release mode on visual studio? it seems its also crashing on realese mode. Or how do i trace the error?

Comment: doe it work ok when you deploy in debug mode?

Comment: yes it does work well

Comment: then I'd try one of the suggestions in my first comment

Comment: Okay let me try that and see

Comment: @Jason thanks alot. I used raygun and found out that on release mode i cannot sent clear text over HTTP even though i had set useClearText to true. Thanks alot

Comment: @DanielMunga Now you have any way to solve your problem?